# Errors Saving in SQL server

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to save my textboxes in SQL server.

But i'm getting some errors.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click
    Dim strconnection As String = "Data Source=EASMAR-PC;Initial Catalog=DatabaseConnection;Integrated Security=True;"
    Dim _cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strconnection)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    _cn.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblCustomer([ID],[Name], [Email], [Address], [DeptID]) VALUES (@ID, @Name, @Email, @Address, @DeptID);"
    cmd.Connection = _cn
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Me.txtIDD.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Me.txtName.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Me.txtEmail.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Me.txtAddress.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeptID", Me.txtIDD.Text)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Me._DataAdapter.Fill(Me._DataSet)
End Sub
```

The error is:

> invalid column DeptID.

And if i took out this line of code

```
 (cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeptID", Me.txtIDD.Text))
```

another error comes up:

> pimary key violation./cannot insert duplicate...

i have 2 tables:

> - tblCustomer: ID-Name-Address-Email
> - tblDept: DeptID-Namee

And if i did this:

```
     Private Sub cmdSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click
            Dim strconnection As String = "Data Source=EASMAR-PC;Initial Catalog=DatabaseConnection;Integrated
 Security=True;"
             Dim _cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strconnection)
             Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
             _cn.Open()
             cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblCustomer([ID],[Name], [Email], [Address],[DeptID]) VALUES (@ID, @Name, @Email,
 @Address,@DeptID);"
             cmd.Connection = _cn
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Me.tt.Text)
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Me.txtName.Text)
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Me.txtEmail.Text)
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Me.txtAddress.Text)
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeptID", Me.txtIDD.Text)

             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
             Me._DataAdapter.Fill(Me._DataSet)
         End Sub
```

I get this error:

> invalid column name ID.

Comment: Are the data type of the columns match with the passing parameters? i.e. Is `ID` column is `varchar`?

Comment: The first error is because `tblCustomer` does not have a column `DeptId` that is in `tblDept`. From what I can see there is not key between the two either. The second error is probably because you have a unique key on `ID` in the `tblCustomer` and are trying to insert an ID that already exists.

Answer (score 1):

You have two tables:

> 1. tblCustomer: ID-Name-Address-Email
> 2. tblDept: DeptID-Namee

How can you insert **DeptID** to **tblCustomer** if thers is **no** such **column** in the **tblCustomer**

**Correct Code for inserting into tblCustomer**

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblCustomer([ID],[Name], [Email], [Address]) VALUES (@ID, @Name, @Email, @Address);"
```

**Correct Code for inserting into tblDept**

```
 cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblCustomer([DeptID],[Namee]) VALUES (@DeptID, @Namee);"
```

Comment: Invalid column name ID :/

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, the `DeptID` column is in another table. You cannot insert that column in the `tblCustomer` where it doesn't exists. You need two separate statements to insert. One for the `tblCustomer` without the `DeptID` column and one for the table `tblDept`

A tentative solution could be

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
_cn.Open()
cmd.Connection = _cn
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblCustomer([ID],[Name], [Email], [Address]) " + 
                  "VALUES (@ID, @Name, @Email, @Address)"
.... add parameters without DeptID
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

cmd = new SqlCommand()
cmd.Connection = _cn
cmd.CommantText = "INSERT INTO tblDept VALUES(@DeptID, @deptName)"

... add parameters for the second insert....

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Also keep in mind that when you need to insert two records in the same batch of statements you should ask yourself if you want to be sure that both the insert succeds or neither. In the second case you need to encapsulate both query using a transaction block. [See here an introductory article on transactions](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-transactions)

Answer (score 0):

I think the error in

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblCustomer([ID],[Name], [Email], [Address], **[DeptID]**) VALUES (@ID, @Name, @Email, @Address, @DeptID);"
```

Please make Sure Correct Column Name in Your Insert query